# Pywhatkit not sending messages through remote server

Tags: python, alert, whatsapp

I have a very simple python whatsapp alert script as below:

```
import pywhatkit
import pyautogui
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
import win32com.client

keyboard = Controller()

def send_whatsapp_alert(msg):
    try:
        pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group_instantly(
            group_id = "GROUP_ID",
            message = msg
        )

        time.sleep(10)
        
        pyautogui.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        print("WhatsApp alert sent!")

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        print("There was an error sending the whatsapp message")
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0x0)
        
        mail.To = 'myemail'

        mail.Subject = "WHATSAPP ALERT FAIL"
        mail.Body = "whatsapp alert has failed. Please check."

        mail.Display()
        mail.Save()
        mail.Send()

send_whatsapp_alert('test')
```

The program will attempt to send a whatsapp message using the pywhatkit library, and if it encounters any issues while trying to send the whatsapp message, it will catch the error and send an email notifying me. The issue is that I am running this code from a remote desktop, and whenever I dont have that remote connection window open, the program does not send me a whatsapp message OR email. I understand that the pywhatkit library has to be run on the same window as the programme due to its nature, but this doesnt seem to apply.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? and if so can you please guide me on how to work around this? Thanks in advance!

I have tried running the program on the remote desktop and it works fine as long as I don't minimize the remote desktop window. If I minimize the remote desktop window, it will NOT send any whatsapp message/email. The expected outcome should be either one, but neither is being sent.